# How to import selenium web elements

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, element

[image]

Is there any way to scrape these  ...  tags at once?

I want to get all ... off that page!

URL = 'https://school.programmers.co.kr/learn/challenges?order=recent&page=1'

Answer (score 0):

The table is rendered using API requests and JavaScript.

Here's the code the extract it (without selenium)

```
import pandas
import requests

dfs = []
for page in range(1, 31): # There are total 591 enteries and 20 per page, that's why 30 pages
    params = {
        'perPage': 20,
        'order': 'recent',
        'page': page,
    }

    response = requests.get(
        'https://school.programmers.co.kr/api/v1/school/challenges/',
        params=params,
    )

    dfs.append(pandas.DataFrame(response.json()['result']))
    print(f'Downloaded from page {page}')
    pandas.concat(dfs).to_csv('Results.csv', index=None)
```

This gets results from each page, appends to the previous data, and saves it.

Sample output of saved CSV:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to extract xpath in the same way?

Comment: That's possible @unj, but I used this one because browser automation using Selenium is comparatively slower.